# Sharing a common fragment among multiple Classic email templates

Tags: visualforce, email-template, static-resources, salesforce-classic

I have tons of classic HTML (with classic letter header) email templates in a classic org.

All of the emails share a common HTML disclosure that is text with some hyperlinks. To ensure consistency in the text content, I would like to consolidate this into a single reference-able component/static resource/something. See below where GroupSpecificSignature and EmailDisclosure are both HTML static resources that have the text and hyperlinks needed.

This doesn't appear to be possible with static resources, so it seems I may have to use Visualforce Email Templates.

A lightning implementation is planned sometime soon as well, so not sure if Visualforce Email Templates are advisable or not.

```
Hello {!Contact.Name},

This is a nice email. 

Thanks, 

{!$Resource.GroupSpecificSignature}

{!$Resource.EmailDisclosure}
```

NOTE: Custom labels are not an option as the disclosure is 1500 characters.

Comment: @identigral , to confirm... there is no other possible ways to dynamically add HTML/Text content (not images) besides a Visualforce Template and would be recommended even with an upcoming switch to lightning? Ex: Would be supported in lightning email templates? I essentially want to "merge" content into the page without being tied to a specific record.

Comment: You can use Classic email templates (incl. VF template) in Lightning. "New" Lightning templates that use HML and enhanced letterhead might work for your use case. It's best to create a new question for Lightning.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to place dynamic content in Salesforce Classic HTML or Saleforce Custom HTML templates such text, HTML, or Images.